# $\vert v \vert^{a}- \vert u \vert ^{a} \leq C_{a} \vert v-u \vert ^a$ for $0<a<2$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

We have the following lemma:

> $\textbf{Lemma}$ If $0<a\leq 1$, for any $u,v \geq 0 $, it holds that
> \begin{equation}
>  (u+v)^a \leq u^a +v^b. 
> \end{equation}
> If $a>1$, for any $u,v \geq 0$, it holds that
> \begin{equation}
>  (u+v)^a \leq 2^{a-1} (u^a +v^a). 
> \end{equation}

Using the lemma, I found
\begin{equation}
\vert v \vert^a - \vert u \vert^a \leq \vert v-u \vert^{a},
\end{equation}
for $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $0< a \leq 1$. However, I cannot find $C_{a}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\vert v \vert^a -\vert u\vert^a \leq C_a \vert v-u \vert^a,
\end{equation}
for $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $1< a <2$.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For $a > 1$ we have $ v^a \leq 2^{a-1} u^a + 2^{a-1}|v- u|^a$.

Comment: But, $2^{a-1}>1$ for $a>1$. How to deal with $(2^{a-1}-1) \vert u \vert^a$?